# c++ vector<uint64_t> read/write disjoint elements data race issue

Tags: c++, concurrency

Say that I have the following code:

```cpp
std::vector<uint64_t> vec;
vec.resize(10);

// thread1
void bar() {
  // read the first 5 elements of vec;
}
// thread2
void foo() {
  // modify the last 5 elements of vec;
}
```

Will there be any potential data race issue(UB)? For example, synchronization issue, compiler instruction reorder issue

Comment: From the C++ point of view, you're doing different things to different elements. There's no race.

Comment: As long as you touch different elements, it is not UB. But be careful about synchronization. If you call `foo();bar();`, you do not have much guarantees that the anything else will see the reads before writes unless you add some memory barriers or other synchronization primitives.

Comment: Main problem will be surprising slow code caused by "false sharing". So if use of memory is extensive it would be more optimal to have two separate vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not create a race condition as long as you access different elements in this vector. Race conditions occur when threads attempt to access the same specific element in shared memory simultaneously.But I suggest that every time you use multithreading in your code, you should consider adding a mutex. It will add some computation cost to your code but also it will add much more security.

Comment: Also, consider using two vectors in this problem. This code can be slow, especially with very large vectors.